# How to cast column within select query

Tags: sql, psycopg2, psql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE name LIKE '%ka%' OR 
tel LIKE '%12%' OR 
address LIKE '%ka%';
```

but `tel` is an integer-type column and therefore I can't use the `%abc%` operator there (although I need to do it like that)

How can I cast the `tel` column within this query?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  Are there other questions that you have?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE name LIKE '%ka%' OR 
CAST(tel as text) LIKE '%12%' OR 
address LIKE '%ka%';
```

Comment: `The column varchar doesn't exist`

Comment: Allright, your lead got me to the right answer:
`CAST (tel as text) LIKE ...`

Comment: Well, that's cause you didn't tell the database. Try the new edit

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `tel` to a `text` type first

```
cast(tel as text) LIKE '%12%' OR
```

You should consider changing your column type, if you are not using an `int` type like an `int`

Indexes and other db optimizations are ineffective with a query like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE name LIKE '%ka%' OR 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, tel) LIKE '%12%' OR 
address LIKE '%ka%';
```